# Membership databae Doesn't Work With IIS 6

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, iis, asp.net-membership, membership-provider

I have a membership database created through the wizard of aspnet_regsql and used in an ASP.NET application that has a login control

the login control was working just fine on IIS Express
but once I deployed it on local IIS it kept displaying the error message

> Your login attempt was not successful. Please try again.

I'm sure I gave the right user name and password and that IIS can connect to the database

Answer (score 0):

If [PasswordFormat](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.sqlmembershipprovider.passwordformat%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is stored as Encrypted, Membership Provider's encryption mechanism uses machine key.

Even if you use Hashed, rule of thumb is to include [Machine Key](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649308.aspx) in web.config.

**Note:** there is an updated version of ASP.Net Membership Provider called [ASP.NET Universal Providers](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/IntroducingSystemWebProvidersASPNETUniversalProvidersForSessionMembershipRolesAndUserProfileOnSQLCompactAndSQLAzure.aspx).